# Python - SportsReference / sportsipy - Difficulty running single team (NFL) code

Tags: python

Just getting going on [sportsipy](https://github.com/roclark/sportsipy) and running into issue when I try to pull information for one NFL team.

1. When I run this code - I get the stats for all teams with no problems:

```
from sportsipy.nfl.teams import Teams
teams = Teams()
for team in teams:
   print(team.rush_yards_per_attempt)
```

However when I run the below for extracting any single team I get a number of errors. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

```
from sportsipy.nfl.teams import Teams
teams = Teams('MIA')
for team in teams:
   print(team.rush_yards_per_attempt)
```

Errors:

```
File "nfl1.py", line 3, in 
teams = Teams('MIA')
File "/Users/--/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sportsipy/nfl/teams.py", line 598, in init
team_data_dict, year = _retrieve_all_teams(year, season_page)
File "/Users/--/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sportsipy/nfl/nfl_utils.py", line 80, in _retrieve_all_teams
doc = utils._pull_page(SEASON_PAGE_URL % year, season_page)
File "/Users/--/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sportsipy/utils.py", line 320, in _pull_page
return pq(url)
File "/Users/--/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyquery/pyquery.py", line 185, in init
html = url_opener(url, kwargs)
File "/Users/--/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyquery/openers.py", line 76, in url_opener
return _requests(url, kwargs)
File "/Users/--e/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyquery/openers.py", line 60, in _requests
raise HTTPError(resp.url, resp.status_code,
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation to [Get a specific NFL team's season information](https://github.com/roclark/sportsipy#id5).

The following code should help you

```
from sportsipy.nfl.teams import Teams
teams = Teams()
mia = teams('MIA')
print(mia.rush_yards_per_attempt)
```